# Deny USB arrival

Tags: c#, usb

I am working on USB Monitor in C# and I wanted to be able to react after the system driver processed arrival and enabled the arriving device, but faster than application level processes (Explorer). I wanted to examine device for autorun.inf and if found to DENY the arrival. I used BROADCAST_QUERY_DENY as described on MSDN but no success. Here is the code (assuming USB arrives as 'I' drive):

```
        switch (msg.Msg)
        {
            case Win32CODES.WM_DEVICECHANGE:
            {
                if (msg.LParam != IntPtr.Zero)
                {
                    DEV_BROADCAST_HDR pHdr = (DEV_BROADCAST_HDR)Marshal.PtrToStructure(msg.LParam, typeof(DEV_BROADCAST_HDR));

                    switch ((int)msg.WParam)
                    {
                        case Win32CODES.DBT_DEVICEARRIVAL:
                        {
                            if (pHdr.dbch_devicetype == Win32CODES.DBT_DEVTYP_VOLUME)
                            {
                                DEV_BROADCAST_VOLUME pVol = (DEV_BROADCAST_VOLUME)Marshal.PtrToStructure(msg.LParam, typeof(DEV_BROADCAST_VOLUME));

                                Char c = GetDriveLetter(pVol.dbcv_unitmask);

                                if (c == 'I')
                                {
                                    msg.Result = new IntPtr(Win32CODES.BROADCAST_QUERY_DENY );

                                    base.WndProc(ref msg);

                                    return;
                                }



                            }

                            break;
                        }
                    }
                }
                break;
            }
        }
        base.WndProc(ref msg);
    }
```

Then I tried another way but again no success.

```
     switch (msg.Msg)
        {
            case Win32CODES.WM_DEVICECHANGE:
            {
                if (msg.LParam != IntPtr.Zero)
                {
                    DEV_BROADCAST_HDR pHdr = (DEV_BROADCAST_HDR)Marshal.PtrToStructure(msg.LParam, typeof(DEV_BROADCAST_HDR));

                    switch ((int)msg.WParam)
                    {
                        case Win32CODES.DBT_DEVICEARRIVAL:
                        {
                            if (pHdr.dbch_devicetype == Win32CODES.DBT_DEVTYP_VOLUME)
                            {
                                DEV_BROADCAST_VOLUME pVol = (DEV_BROADCAST_VOLUME)Marshal.PtrToStructure(msg.LParam, typeof(DEV_BROADCAST_VOLUME));

                                Char c = GetDriveLetter(pVol.dbcv_unitmask);

                                if (c == 'I')
                                {
                                    int bytesReturned = 0;

                                    IntPtr buffer = Marshal.AllocHGlobal(sizeof(int));

                                    SafeFileHandle _hdev = CreateFileR(c.ToString());

                                    bool result = DeviceIoControl(_hdev, CTL_CODE(0x00000033, 0x0400, 0, 1),
                                        IntPtr.Zero, 0, buffer, sizeof(int),
                                        out bytesReturned, IntPtr.Zero);

                                    int sessionId = Marshal.ReadInt32(buffer);

                                    Marshal.FreeHGlobal(buffer);
                                }



                            }

                            break;
                        }
                    }
                }
                break;
            }
        }
        base.WndProc(ref msg);
```

Is there a way to accomplish this? Thanks..

Comment: Not all of the device change messages can be denied. Most of the ones which *do* describe denial relate to device removal. I'd be surprised if `DBT_DEVICEARRIVAL` could be denied, but it would be better if the documentation made all of this clear. I don't think you can write a user mode application in C# that will do what you're trying to do.

Comment: You could try to eject it www.codeproject.com/KB/system/usbeject.aspx

Comment: In what libraries are DEV_BROADCAST_HDR and similar LParam's defined?

Comment: Check MSDN https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa363246(v=vs.85).aspx